# Bad defined sql query date on PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm trying to access to a DB by this way:

```
$query="SELECT VAR1, VAR2  FROM TABLE WHERE DATE1 = TO_DATE('2010/01/01 01:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mm:ss')";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

But I receive this error:
**Warning: oci_execute(): in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\monitorizaR\uploader.php on line 79**

But if I put the codeline by this way, it works..

```
$query="SELECT VAR1, VAR2  FROM TABLE WHERE DATE1 = TO_DATE('2010/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD')";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

For sure is a silly thing about the date format, but I tried a lot of ways to do it.

Regards!

Comment: What is the datatype of `DATE1` and in which format dates are saved there ?

Comment: Its oracle not mysql right ? please add relevant tags only

Comment: When I access to the database by excel it has this format "2010/01/01 01:00:00". Can I know the datatype of `DATE1` with some query?

Comment: You could simply execute `DESCRIBE tablename` to see the structure of your table

Comment: `desc table_name`  or `select data_type from all_tab_columns where owner = 'your_schema' and table_name = 'your_table_name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `minute` part of the date is not correct, it is `mi` not `mm`

```
SELECT
    VAR1, 
    VAR2  
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE1 = TO_DATE('2010/01/01 01:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

You got your date format wrong. Try

```
$query="SELECT VAR1, VAR2  FROM TABLE WHERE DATE1 = TO_DATE('2010/01/01 01:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stmt);
```